# integral of $z^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I know something similar might been asked, but I learn by example. The assignment is to find the integral of $z^{-1}$ in the square with points $(1+i) , (1-i), (-1-i), (-1+i)$

Do we rewrite $z$ as $a+bi$? How is this done?

Comment: Is this a contour integral around the boundary of the indicated square, as $\oint_C\frac{dz}{z}$?

Comment: Edited my OP, @vadim123, why can we write $z^{-1}$ as $dz/z$?

Comment: @MPW I would assume so.  @ Bahbi Begin by noting that $z=0$ is a *pole* of $\frac{1}{z}$ and otherwise it is analytic.  Thus by [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula), you have $f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$ for appropriate choice of $a$ and $f$.  In this case, $f(z)=1$ and $a=0$, you can simplify the above.  If you wish to do this by hand instead of relying on theorems, then note that on each leg of the trip, you only change the real (or imaginary) coordinates.  Do you know how to calculate $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{a-x}$

Comment: @ Bahbi, we can write *the integral of $z^{-1}$ (with respect to $z$)* as the integral of $\frac{1}{z}$ with respect to $z$ as $\int \frac{1}{z} dz$ as $\int \frac{dz}{z}$.  It is not so much that we rewrite $z^{-1}$ as $dz/z$, but that we can rewrite the *integral with respect to*...as... Remember that $z^{-n} = \frac{1}{z^n}$.  Also note that $\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{z-0}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand that $f(a)=1/(2πi)∮f(z)/(z−a)dz$ gives me (with $f(z)=1, a=0$) $f(a)=1/(2πi)$ so what do I do with the square to get my final result?

Comment: If you are asked to do this from first principles, you would parameterize each of the edges of the square, then do four integrals and add.  But if you are to use Cauchy's integral theorem (as WPW hints) then of course it is much easier than that.

Comment: You say $f(a)=1/(2\pi i)$, but that is incorrect.  You wanted to isolate the integral.  Further, you know that $f(a)=1$ for any value of $a$, in particular when $a=0$, so...

Comment: @JMoravitz Why do I know that $f(a)=1$ for all $a$? Would this conclude our integral to be $2πi$

Comment: Read again the statement of cauchy's integral formula.  We wanted to pick a function f and a value a such that f is analytic on the region and also in a convenient way so that it resembles the integral we were curious about in the first place.  It happens that the constant function f (z)=1 is exactly what we wanted to make the integral be what the original question asked about

Comment: It is still worth doing the question at least once without cauchy's integral formula and doing it by hand.  The integral I asked you about in an earlier comment, have you thought about that yet?  Maybe something to do with logarithms?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\gamma$ be the curve traveling along the perimeter of the square with vertices $(1+i),(-1+i),(-1-i),(1-i)$ traveling around the perimeter once in a counter-clockwise direction.  Let us label the edges of the square counterclockwise with edge $1$ being the edge from $(1+i)$ to $(-1+i)$

$\oint_\gamma z^{-1}dz = \int_{\gamma_1} z^{-1}dz + \int_{\gamma_2} z^{-1}dz+\int_{\gamma_3} z^{-1}dz+\int_{\gamma_4} z^{-1}dz$ where $\gamma_n$ is the $n^{th}$ part of the trip traveling along the $n^{th}$ edge.

Let us look at each in more detail.  $\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{dz}{z} = \int_1^{-1} \frac{dx}{x+i}$.  This comes from realizing that we can think of a complex number $z$ instead as the form $x+iy$ where both $x$ and $y$ are real, and that all along the first edge, $y=1$.

We have $\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{dz}{z}=\int_1^{-1}\frac{dx}{x+i} = \ln(-1+i)-\ln(1+i) = \ln(\frac{-1+i}{1+i}) = \ln(\frac{2i}{2})=\ln(i)=\frac{i\pi}{2}$

Continuing in this fashion, find the rest of the integrals $\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{dz}{z}, \int_{\gamma_3}\frac{dz}{z}, \int_{\gamma_4}\frac{dz}{z}$ and then add the results.

---

Alternatively, using Cauchy's Integral Formula and the calculus of residues, we know that for analytic $f$ over a domain $\Omega$, and the boundary of omega $\partial \Omega$, for each $a \in \Omega^\circ$ we have:

$$f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial \Omega} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} dz$$

What this means to us is that if we want to find $\oint \frac{1}{z}dz$ we could write it instead using the above with $f(z)=1$ for all $z$, and $a=0$ as:

$$f(0)=1 = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-0}dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z}dz$$

Multiplying both sides by $2\pi i$ we get $\oint_\gamma \frac{1}{z}dz = 2\pi i$ (*which should agree with your calculations using the first method*).